# Prevent the dough from "oxidizing"?

Tags: baking, dough, pie, acidity

I was practicing and trying to make an apple pie depending on this source: http://allrecipes.com/howto/perfect-pie-crusts/detail.aspx

In the **Liquid** section, it's said: "A little bit of acid--vinegar or lemon juice--helps tenderize the dough and prevents it from **oxidizing**."

What's "Oxidizing"? First time I read/hear this term in cooking?

Please help me learn, I'm still a beginner!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Oxidizing in cooking is same as Oxidizing anything. Plenty of base material on your favourite search engine

Comment: @TFD I still don't get it. So what happens to the dough when it becomes oxidized? Does it taste.. bad? Or it becomes hard to cook, or what? Sorry for the noob-type questions ^_^;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a chemist so I'll let wikipedia do it for me:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxidation

As far as it's culinary effects in crusts- I have seen unreliable reference to the flour oxidizing and developing a off color.

I have never seen this personally and I am skeptical of it. Pie crusts can be made just fine without vinegar. Vinegar does significantly tenderize the crust as well as add an interesting flavor.

Comment: Vinegar on an apple pie crust? Sounds like.. crazy mixture, doesn't it?!

Comment: Not really- vinegar works very well with apples. One of my favorite apple pie fillings has balsamic vinegar in it. Delicious.